# What would be the Time Complexity of peek() in queue using array in Java?

Tags: queue, time-complexity

If we want to implement queue using array then what would be the Time Complexity of the peek() method?

According to me it should be O(1) as we are returning the first element of the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the queue so that `peek()` always returned the first item in the array, then the queue would be very inefficient for remove. If the `peek()` always returned the first element then `remove()` would always have to return the first element. Which means that it would then have to move everything else up one space so that the next item to be removed was at the beginning of the array.

You *could* implement it that way, but `remove()` would have complexity O(n).

A queue with a fixed-size array as the backing store is typically implemented as a circular queue with accompanying `addIndex` and `removeIndex` variables that indicate where the next item should be added or removed.

Imagine a queue of size 5. On construction all five slots are empty and `addIndex` and `removeIndex` are equal to 0. Then, add one item. `addIndex` is equal to 0, so you put the item at the first position in the array. Then you increment `addIndex`. After adding three items, your array contains `[1,2,3,0,0]` and `addIndex = 3`, indicating that the next item will be placed at position 3 in the array.

To remove an item, you return the item that's at `array[removeIndex]`, and increment `removeIndex`. After you remove two items, the array contains `[1,2,3,0,0]`, and `removeIndex = 2`.

Perhaps a picture will give you a better idea how it works:

```
1 2 3 0 0
    ^ ^
    | |
    | AddIndex
    RemoveIndex
```

So what happens if you want to put three more items into the queue? The first two are easy enough, you just add them in the 4th and 5th places. But the sixth item? You wrap around. So after adding three more items, the queue looks like this:

```
6 2 3 4 5
  ^ ^
  | | 
  | RemoveIndex
  AddIndex
```

In this way, all of the operations on the queue, `add`, `remove`, and `peek` have complexity O(1).

In this case, `peek()` is not returning the first element of the array, but rather it's returning the element at `array[removeIndex]`.

So, whereas you're correct in assuming that the time complexity of `peek()` would be O(1), the reason for that is not what you assumed.